# Bash script to enable / disable SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, scripts

Im running ubuntu 14.04 LTS (no GUI)

and im looking to write a `bash` script that does the following:

> 1. Check to see if the ssh service is enabled or disabled
> 2. If enabled, then disable, if disabled then enable.

Every time I run this script it should *turn on/off* the SSH service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small shell script,

```
#!/bin/bash
if `service ssh status | grep -q running`
then
    service ssh stop
    echo "ssh stopped by user"
else
    service ssh start
    echo "ssh started by user" 
fi
```

After saving it as `script.sh`, run it as, (give it execution permission)

```
sudo ./script.sh
```

or without execution permission

```
sudo bash ./script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Dude, one small issue though, I need it to be automated, so i cant be pressing "y" or "n" it needs to work like a switch, running "sh script.sh" should just enable or disable the SSH service automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following in a file named "`toggleSsh.sh`"

```
#!/bin/bash

stat=`status ssh`
echo $stat
#stat is returned like: ssh start/running, process 1602
goal=`echo $stat|cut -f2 -d" "|cut -f1 -d/`
#cut the 2nd field afetr 1st space; then cut the 1st field before "/" to get the "goal" of the ssh job.

#ignoring the status
echo $goal
if [ "$goal" == "start" ];
then
  service ssh stop
else
  service ssh start
fi
```

Run this script as `sudo toggleSsh.sh` since `service` command needs root privilege.

You can finetune the above script by taking into account the status(waiting, starting, pre-start, spawned, post-start, running, pre-stop, stopping, killed or post-stop) of the ssh job, and not just the goal (start/stop.) Read `man status` to understand more about how you can utilise the `status` command.

Comment: Thanks Dude, your a Ledgend, i'll have a play soon, and try get it working :)

Comment: Ok, its not quite working, seems to be an error on line 11, "if [ "$goal" == "start" ];" see verbose output below..

Comment: opps, to long to paste here...

Comment: #!/bin/bash

stat=`status ssh`
echo $stat
ssh start/running, process 1663
#stat is returned like: ssh start/running, process 1602
goal=`echo $stat|cut -f2 -d" "|cut +f1 -d/`
cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
#cut the 2nd field afetr 1st space; then cut the 1st field before "/" to get the "goal" of the ssh job.

#ignoring the status
echo $goal

if [ "$goal" == "start" ];
then
  service ssh stop
else
  service ssh start
fi
ssh.sh: 11: [: unexpected operator
start: Job is already running: ssh

Comment: ffs! this website suX!

Comment: make sure there is a space after each of these: if, [. "$goal", ==, "start". Bash scripts are very sensitive to spaces. I've checked it on my system and it works.

Comment: :) cut -f1, not +f1.

Comment: sorry, yeah there are spaces between the == and i've changed the +f1, still getting error: [: unexpected operator start: Job is already running: ssh

Comment: im running the script with the command: sudo sh script.sh, if that makes any differnce, i get a permission error without sudo.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but the 2nd answer seems to have nailed it. Cheers for all your help guys :D